# create an API with .NET Minimal APIs that require session api key

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This video is really nice and shows how to create Minimal APIs using .net 6:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRJFNGIsJEo

It is amazing how it uses dependency injection to get mostly everything that you need inside your endpoints. For example if I need the value of a custom header I would have this:

```
app.MapGet("/get-custom-header", ([FromHeader(Name = "User-Agent")] string data) =>
{
    return $"User again is: {data}";
});
```

I can have another endpoint where I have access to the entire httpContext like this:

```
app.MapGet("/foo", (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext c) =>
{
    var path = c.Request.Path;
    return path;
});
```

I can even register my own classes with this code: `builder.Services.AddTransient<TheClassIWantToRegister>()`

If I register my custom classes I will be able to create an instance of that class every time I need it on and endpoint (`app.MapGet("...`)

---

**Anyways back to the question.** When a user logs in I send him this:

```
{
  "ApiKey": "1234",
  "ExpirationDate": blabla bla
  .....
}
```

The user must send the `1234` token to use the API. **How can I avoid repeating my code like this:**

```
app.MapGet("/getCustomers", ([FromHeader(Name = "API-KEY")] string apiToken) =>
{
    // validate apiToken agains DB
    if(validationPasses)
       return Database.Customers.ToList();
    else
       // return unauthorized
});
```

I have tried creating a custom class `RequiresApiTokenKey` and registering that class as `builder.Services.AddTransient<RequiresApiTokenKey>()` so that my API knows how to create an instance of that class when needed but how can I access the current http context inside that class for example? **How can I avoid having to repeat having to check if the header API-KEY header is valid in every method that requires it?**

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, but you should be able to use middleware in a similar way to dotnet5 api. something like, app.UseMiddleware<MyApiKeyCheck>(); the middleware has access to the HttpContext.Request.Headers where you could do the checks you need

Comment: although not for dotnet 6, I'd bet the pattern is the same.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gave this a test based on my comments.

This would call the method Invoke in the middleware on each request and you can do checks here.

Probably a better way would be to use the `AuthenticationHandler`. using this would mean you can attribute individual endpoints to have the API key check done instead of all incoming requests

But, I thought this was still useful, middleware can be used for anything you'd like to perform on every request

#### Using Middleware

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

//our custom middleware extension to call UseMiddleware
app.UseAPIKeyCheckMiddleware();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

APIKeyCheckMiddleware.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

internal class APIKeyCheckMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public APIKeyCheckMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        
        //we could inject here our database context to do checks against the db
        if (httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("API-KEY", out StringValues value))
        {
            //do the checks on key
            var apikey = value;
        }
        else
        {
            //return 403
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        }
        
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class APIKeyCheckMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAPIKeyCheckMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        
        return builder.UseMiddleware<APIKeyCheckMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I have some remarks: it only worked for me when the await _next(httpContext); is executed only after a successful authorization: in the "//do the checks on" key block. It must not be done after setting the StatusCode to 403.  Next maybe it is better to use StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden instead of writing out just the code (403).

Answer (score 3):

I used SmithMart's answer but had to change things in the Invoke method and used DI in the constructor.
Here's my version:

```
internal class ApiKeyCheckMiddleware
    {
        public static string ApiKeyHeaderName = "X-ApiKey";
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<ApiKeyCheckMiddleware> _logger;
        private readonly IApiKeyService _apiKeyService;

        public ApiKeyCheckMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ApiKeyCheckMiddleware> logger, IApiKeyService apiKeyService)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
            _apiKeyService = apiKeyService;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var request = httpContext.Request;
            var hasApiKeyHeader = request.Headers.TryGetValue(ApiKeyHeaderName, out var apiKeyValue);

            if (hasApiKeyHeader)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Found the header {ApiKeyHeader}. Starting API Key validation", ApiKeyHeaderName);

                if (apiKeyValue.Count != 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apiKeyValue))
                {
                    if (Guid.TryParse(apiKeyValue, out Guid apiKey))
                    {
                        var allowed = await _apiKeyService.Validate(apiKey);

                        if (allowed)
                        {
                            _logger.LogDebug("Client successfully logged in with key {ApiKey}", apiKeyValue);

                            var apiKeyClaim = new Claim("ApiKey", apiKeyValue);
                            var allowedSiteIdsClaim = new Claim("SiteIds", string.Join(",", allowedSiteIds));
                            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { apiKeyClaim, allowedSiteIdsClaim }, "ApiKey"));
                            httpContext.User = principal;

                            await _next(httpContext);

                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    _logger.LogWarning("Client with ApiKey {ApiKey} is not authorized", apiKeyValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("{HeaderName} header found, but api key was null or empty", ApiKeyHeaderName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("No ApiKey header found.");
            }

            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        }
    }
```